# HTML: Equal HTML, different View

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design-lite

I have a very very weird bug I am debugging right now.

I am trying out Material Design Lite: http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section

But whenever I just COPY/PASTE the "Fixed Header" example from their official CodePen (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WvaKjK) it looks different in my browser:

[image: Look at the Icon in the Top Left]

And this is the whole HTML that is used:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Material Design Lite -->
  <script src="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.1/material.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.1/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  <!-- Material Design icon font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Always shows a header, even in smaller screens. -->
  <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header">
      <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
        <!-- Title -->
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
        <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
        <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
        <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
          <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
      <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
      <div class="page-content">
        <!-- Your content goes here -->
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you compare the two headers, you see that the icon in the top left is not in place. Well the queston arises for the why.

Because I use the **same** code on my machine, which makes the icon appear out of place, but whenever I **copy/paste** the code from my browser by f.e. cmd+U to jsfiddle or codepen, I get the Icon placed right.

See here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVgBzZ

It's not a browser problem, since the same problem appears also in Firefox, Chrome, Chrome Canary and also Android Chrome. I uploaded the same HTML here, which is displayed wrongly:

http://temp.leavingblue.com/5.html

I ran the code on my local machine on windows (wamp) and on a linux virtual machine (homestead).

**TL;DR:**

Same HTML looks fine in Official getmdl.io site, codepen, jsfiddle, but looks weird when I recreate it on my own HTML file.

**How to reproduce the error**

Go to

1. http://temp.leavingblue.com/5.html,
2. Cmd + U
3. Copy/Paste all to Codepen.io
4. Look at differences

Can anyone reproduce the error? Also has anyone an explanation for this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I open [this link](http://temp.leavingblue.com/5.html) and found the following reason that icon is not allign

//Set line-height: 40px; in below css

```
.mdl-layout__drawer-button {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 48px;
  width: 48px;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 26px;
  line-height: 50px; //change here
  font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
  margin: 10px 12px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: rgb(255,255,255);
  z-index: 4;
}
```

and

line-height: 1; //remove this from below css

```
.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;  //remove this from here
  letter-spacing: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  display: inline-block;
  word-wrap: normal;
  -webkit-font-feature-settings: 'liga';
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
```

reason it's allign in your fiddle, you have not added the css `.mdl-layout__drawer-button` so `line-height` is causing the problem

HERE IS YOUR ERROR

repalce this `<html>` with this `<!DOCTYPE html>` it's self explained

[working fix](http://shehary.com/stackoverflow/check.html)

Comment: Sorry, I still do not get it. Why is it working in codepen.io or in the code snippet above but not on the link I posted? From my understanding I reference both times a cdn and I don't use any CSS File at all in all the links I posted. (Just in jsfiddle, because jsfiddle has trouble recognizing the link to the icons.

Comment: simple answer, one css is over written by other, in this case best way to use your own customized css is with `!important` or try to change the position of included css files, remember if you have 3 css file, like 1, 2 and 3, the 3rd file will overwrite the 1 and 2, becuase its coming in last and browser will read it last and prefer it over 1 and 2

Comment: This comes down to CSS Specificity. Font needs to be included before MDL CSS (also since it may cause issues in other ways for niche cases.) Since font CSS comes in later, it gets higher priority than MDL CSS, so the icons CSS is overriding the line height set by MDL.

Comment: Changing the priority of the Font (including it before MDL CSS) doesn't make a difference. Removing it, of course does. Yet the question has not be answered, why the SAME code makes different results.

Comment: check my answer, at the end

Answer (score 1):

All that was missing was a single line at the top of the document

```
<!doctype html>
```

As it seems the editors include it automatically.

Comment: really, after 2 mins of my updated answer you are posting your answer and telling others that this is the problem

Comment: I didn't saw your update. I downloaded the complete source of one of their working templates and stripped it down piece by piece until the only difference was the Doctype. Nonetheless I am highly grateful for your contribution and have accepted your answer as the correct one. Thanks mate.

Comment: yeah i spent 30 mins just to sort this out, reproduce everything on my server, compare and figure out, so makes me little angry when i saw you posted the answer after my updated  answer, my oppolgies and you are most welcome